# Multicolumn block is narrower than the surrounding text

Tags: multicol, framed, width

I need to typeset blocks of text in a multicolumn environment, with a title above, and framed with full line width.

I'm using the `multicol` package for that. The issue I face is that the block of text (in the `multicols` environment) appears to be narrower than the title.

According to the `multicol` documentation, it should work fine :

> The space between columns is
>   controlled by the length parameter `\columnsep`.
>   The width
>   for the individual columns is
>   automatically calculated from
>   this parameter and the current
>   `\linewidth`.

However it doesn't :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\fbox{
  \begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
    Title
  \end{minipage}
}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1-5]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: The tite box is wider for two reasons: a) you have a space after `\fbox{` which ends up inside the frame and b) as pointed out the width of the `\fbox` is width of content + 2*`\fboxsep`, so you need to reduce the width of the minipage accordingly or use `\framebox`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's caused by the padding that `fbox` has, the easiest solution is to use `framebox` because it's possible to specify the width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\framebox[\linewidth][l]{
    Title
}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1-5]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Which results in the following:

[image: Result]

If for some reason you absolutely need the `minipage`, you can use this:

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\framebox[\linewidth]{
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    Title
    \end{minipage}
}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1-5]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Note that this eliminates any horizontal padding, so text inside will now look like this:

[image: Result]

But this is easily fixed by adding `\hspace{1mm}` before `Title`:

[image: Hspace]

Comment: The title will be centered eventually. And no I didn't need the minipage except to specify the width.

Comment: @T.Verron: You can center it by using `\framebox[\linewidth][c]` or just `\framebox[\linewidth]`.

Comment: I meant "horizontally centered", as a justification about why I don't really care about horizontal padding. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

It's always good to create macros for things you might be doing often, for the sake of consistency (see [Consistent typography](http://goo.gl/792Wc)). So, perhaps `\myheading` or `\myheading*` could be used:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,xparse,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{multicol,xparse,lipsum}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myheading}{s O{\bfseries} m}{%
  \noindent
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\framebox[\linewidth][l]{#2#3}}
    {\makebox[\linewidth]{%
      \framebox[\dimexpr\linewidth+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule][l]{#2#3}}}%
}
\begin{document}

\myheading{Title}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[6]
\end{multicols}

\myheading[\slshape]{\hfill Title\hfill}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[6]
\end{multicols}

\myheading*{Title}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[6]
\end{multicols}

\myheading*[\itshape]{\hfill Title}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[6]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

The marginal difference between `\myheading` and `\myheading*` is that the former sets the title to align with the text block, while the latter sets the framed box to align with the text block (as in [Silex' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79201/5764)). The optional argument sets the font of the heading - **bold** or `\bfseries` by default. [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provides the macro programming interface.

---

Some more detail: The `s O{<stuff>} m` specification for `\myheading` allows for

- a starred variant of `\myheading` because of the `s` parameter. There, it essentially creates two macros `\myheading` and `\myheading*`;
- an optional first argument - due to the `O{<stuff>}` parameter - that defaults to `<stuff>` if it's not supplied; and
- a mandatory argument - as a result of `m` - used to typeset the title.

`\IfBooleanTF` is used to condition between the supplied argument. In this case, I've used `\IfBooleanTF{#1}`, so the function will condition on whether you supplied a `*` or not. If you did, the first condition is executed:

```
\framebox[\linewidth][l]{#2#3}
```

This will set `#2` - the optional argument (defaulting to `\bfseries` if it is not supplied) - and `#3` - the mandatory argument (title). If no star is supplied, the second condition is executed:

```
\makebox[\linewidth]{%
  \framebox[\dimexpr\linewidth+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule][l]{#2#3}}
```

This sets a box of width `\linewidth` and inside it a `\framebox`. The reason for the `\makebox` is to make TeX think that the box will only be as wide as the line, even though it actually stretches beyond that. The default behaviour of `\makebox[\linewidth]` is to centre its contents, similar to `\makebox[\linewidth][c]`. The `\framebox` has a width of `\linewidth+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule` since the interior content has to fit within `\linewidth`, but there's an added frame separation and rule on *both* sides of it - left and right. Just like with `\makebox`, `\framebox` has an additional optional argument for horizontal adjustment, set to `[l]`eft aligned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Those are interesting alternatives, and the ultimate goal is indeed to have a macro for my headings, mainly because I will have many other things to tweak in these headers. However, it seems to me as if your macro `\myheading*` does exactly the same as the answer Silex offered, with `\framebox` (except for the ability to add a font specification). I doubt all these lines of code I don't understand are useless, so if there's a way you can explain them simply, I'd be really curious.

Comment: @T.Verron: I've added some explanation of my code.